# Efficient way to rank() on Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a three column dataframe on PySpark, on which I'm trying to do the equivalent of `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` on SQL. The dataframe `df` looks like:

```
col1, col2, score
A   , B   , 0.500
...
```

I know I can use window functions for this:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(df['col1']).orderBy(df['score'].desc())
df = df.select('col1', 'col2', 'score', F.rank().over(windowSpec).alias('rnk'))
```

For a very large `df`, this would need to spend a lot of time shuffling data across partitions. Is there any way to make this more efficient? (I don't need to use a dataframe, if not necessary.)

Comment: It's hard to avoid shuffling when there is partitionBy envolved. Even with RDD, a `byKey` operation would be needed, causing some shuffle. I'm not sure there is a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the comment by @DanieldePaula; in  Spark SQL it is tricky (/usually not possible) to avoid shuffles. I have had discussions with the shepherd of spark sql Michael Armbrust about this - and the rationale is that non-expert users could end up with incorrect results if permitted to use the equivalent of `preservesPartioning=true` (from many of the core `RDD` operations) in spark sql queries.

In any case for *your* query it would be particularly difficult to achieve the results without a shuffle  - since your data is not even already properly pre-partitioned.

If you wish to achieve better performance you would need to:

- drop out of spark sql entirely
- pre-partition the data according to the desired windows
- perform the equivalent of your windowed operations manuallly - via the core `RDD` primitives.

Now those sound sort of *seriously* onerous..  So .. you will probably just want to live with the performance you have from the windowing.